# Star that gives heat but no light?

Tags: stars, light

Is a star that emits heat, enough for life to exist on its planets, however does not emit much light possible?

NOTE: I'm not asking if life on a lightless planet is possible.

Comment: I don't think you can have a fusion reaction that is so low energy that only infrared and radio waves are released with no visible light wavelengths.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so, either.

Comment: Well, there is technically a black dwarf, but no fusion there.

Comment: Those don't preduce much heat, right?

Comment: They don't "produce heat" so much as they just dissipate it. They are huge and started hot so have lots of thermal mass and stored thermal energy that is released over time. Brown dwarfs are apparently a bit hotter and maybe about as hot as an oven, and even your oven can glow red. I'm not sure a giant oven from a millions km away will do you any good. It might, if your planet is really, really close. But you're going to need a thermal gradient to extract energy from it which is a bit of a problem. Did you know there are form of life that do not rely on the sun? Like chemosynthensis?

Comment: "No light" - no light whatsoever, or faint red glow is acceptable?

Comment: Faint red glow is acceptable. Here, I'll change the question.

Comment: This query is probably more suitable for Astronomy.  Here, we'd like to help you sort out any issues or problems you're having with your own fictional world and how things work within it. We'd need rather more fictional world context for this question to be a good fit here!

Comment: This is a non-question. All you're really asking is, given star A, what's the outer limit of the habitable zone? How you want to reference the question doesn't actually change the question. (E.G., you can ask what's 2+3 or 3+2 or 5-3 or 5-2... they're all the same question, just looked at in different ways.)

Comment: Oh, and please keep something in mind. Stars basically one thing: photons. They don't emit "heat." Some of those photons are in the visible spectrum. Most aren't. That's why you're really only asking what the outer limit of a star's habitable zone is... because a planet needs enough photons to heat it to habitable temperatures. So, there isn't "light" and "heat," there's only photons.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39970/7472)

Comment: @ioi  This question - https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/can-a-star-emit-heat-but-no-visible-light -  has four answers, including one of mine, which goes into some detail about the possibilities of life on a lightless world.

Comment: @JBH: Sure, but if the temperature of your star is such that essentially all the photons are emitted in the infrared, it's lightless.

Comment: @jamesqf that's a cool idea. Do we know of any stars like this? That would make a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is called a [brown dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf). The line between a very small and dim dwarf star and a very large gas giant that is also a [rogue planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet) is a bit fuzzy, but brown dwarfs actually have a weak fusion reaction inside.